# Injecting into existing constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm having some difficulties trying to inject a service into another in Angular. I'm trying to create a service by extending another class with an existing constructor, as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpService extends AuthHttp {
    constructor(options: AuthConfig, http: Http, defOpts?: RequestOptions) {
        super(options, http, defOpts);
    }
}
```

My issue is: I need to inject another service into it and I can't seem to put it as argument in the constructor (can't put a required argument after an optional one and if I put it as optional with ? then it doesn't work).

I've tried with `injector.get` and it works reasonably well but it injects a different instance of the service than the other components and is breaking my app (I rely on some service properties to show information).

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: What parameter do you want to add? Where did you register a provider for this parameter? What is the error message you get? What about adding it before the optional parameter?

Answer (score 1):

To inject another service, just add it to the constructor *before* the optional parameter. Then it will be fine.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpService extends AuthHttp {
    constructor(options: AuthConfig, http: Http, 
                otherservice: OtherService,
                defOpts?: RequestOptions) {
        super(options, http, defOpts);
    }
}
```